# Removing a / from the address bar?

Tags: html, directory

I've always seen this on websites but I've never actually known how to do it. If the title is unclear then here is what I mean.

```
http://domain.com/directory/
```

I want to change that into:

```
http://domain.com/directory
```

I've seen other websites do it and I just wondered how I would go about doing that. Not even sure if this is the correct place to be posting this but I have no idea. If I am posting in the wrong place then please direct me to somewhere else. Thank you.

Comment: [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)

Comment: do you know what the actual code would be or not? because I couldn't find anything for this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is good for the SEO and it will set default to the root of your domain on the server where you have uploaded the web pages. It is something you don't need to worry about. It pretty much gets the search engines to look at all the files and not just the index.html file